# CMake build and project directories

Tags: cmake

I wonder to know why projects structures has folders like `bin` and `lib` but normally (at least in tutorials I saw), people creates a folder named `build` and use `cmake ..`.

Is it the right way to use `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin` or `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin` to build a project?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, a good starting point for directory structures would be https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html. Note that this applies to the install dir. It can help to have the install dir and the corresponding source somewhat related when possible. Building completely outside of the source or in the source under a build subdirectory is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Imagine that I have severals libraries and an application uses those libraries. Isn't it better to have the libraries files on the library directory? The install moves the files to another directory BUT what if I need the library to be used in my application? - I did this, I separated the application in separated libraries and I just include them as libraries.

Comment: If you need the library to be used in your application, it is all the same, with the caveat that if you are building your libraries as shared objects, you will need to make sure that the application links to the installed version of the library (see http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling for more). If the libraries are exclusively used by your application, you can always link statically in which case you don't even have to install the libraries. The place where the libraries live in the build directory is mostly your personal choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, people using CMake often do build in a different directory (e.g. one called `build`).  That's called "out of source" building, and it's useful because it helps keep built artifacts out of your source tree so you don't check them in.

As for `bin` and `lib`, those are the conventional names on Unix-like systems for directories storing executable files and libraries respectively.  It's good to keep your build artifacts separated this way because it makes it clear where to look for things you can run vs. things you can build against.  A common setup in CMake would be to have a `build` directory containing `bin` and `lib` within--if your build rules are set up properly, CMake will create `bin` and `lib` when you run your build.

Comment: Good explanation. I think that I will use the "out of source" way.